# Save form state for redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm working on a project in which I have a form, a part of this form is a button which authenticates with a 3rd party service, they click the button, are redirected to the authentication page, then redirected back to the form. When they return I'd like the form to be in the same state it was when they left the page, but I'm not sure of a good way to do this. It's a large form so users would be annoyed if they had to fill it all out again.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default you define `new` method as an instance of object without any data:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

However, it is possible to instantiate object with default values:

```
def new_with_data
  @post = Post.new(title: 'Some default title')
end
```

Therefore, when you want to store state of form and display it on next page, without storing it in database, you can store it in session / cookie / params (e.g. GET, if they are not sensitive or POST, if you just want to show it on next page; carry data to next view).

```
def confirm_form_data
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
end
```

Of course, you don't have to use any models here:

```
def confirm_data
  @data = params[:post]
  # use @data in your view
end
```